# What is this semi-circular symbol in the middle of a formula?

Tags: notation, formal-languages

I have tried every search term I can think of but I can find no way of knowing what this symbol between the (a) and the trP means:

[image: Symbol]

Some context [here, Point 2 in the third paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes#Formal_semantics). Original image from a lecture on CSP, so can't link to that one specifically, but I'm pretty sure this is in the same context.

Comment: That's like when you run a quarter and a half note together.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: A bit more context would help: what are $a$ and $tr_P$? (The symbol often indicates a concatenation of strings.)

Comment: Some context here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes#Formal_semantics (Point 2 in the third paragraph)

Comment: Original image from a lecture on CSP, so can't link to that one specifically, but I'm pretty sure this is in the same context.

Comment: So... What does this have to do with set theory or logic?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I dunno, it's logical algebra isn't it? Set theory I admit was probably a bad tag. I think (a) is like a set of one thing. Was struggling to tag it to be honest not knowing what the symbol did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it used in [Communicating Sequentional Processes](http://usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf), by C. A. R. Hoare. In it, he defines the symbol as (page xvii)

> (between traces)
>   followed by
>
> $$\text{For example, } \langle a,b,c \rangle=\langle a,b \rangle \text{ (symbol) } \langle \rangle \text{ (symbol) } \langle c \rangle$$

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, didn't realise it was specific to CSP, thank you for being more intuitive than I clearly am :P

Comment: @LeonAves Thanks, but I just found it through brute force via a search engine.

Comment: @LeonAves This not specific to CSP, it is part of the [Z-Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation) which is an ISO standard (ISO/IEC 13568:2002) (again found by search engine).